# How to get placeholder image url Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, placeholder

How to get the placeholder image URL on my template file of product listing page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    use  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager $storeManager
    
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $path =
    catalog/placeholder/thumbnail_placeholder OR
    catalog/placeholder/swatch_image_placeholder OR
    catalog/placeholder/small_image_placeholder OR
    catalog/placeholder/image_placeholder OR
    
     public function getConfig($config_path)
        {
            return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getConfig($config_path);
        }


    $mediaUrl = $this ->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );

<img src = $mediaUrl.'catalog/product/placeholder/'.$this->getConfig($path) />
```

On Magento 2.2:

- Get Helper in Block (phtml)
  `$imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);`
- Get Helper Global
  `$imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);`
- Get Placeholder Image Url. User as parameter: 'image', 'smal_image', 'swatch_image' or 'thumbnail'.
  `$placeholderImageUrl = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');`

Comment: Hi saurabh there is a / missing after "placeholder" while getting image source . Also $mediaUrl should be above the img tag, please correct.

Comment: yes thanks aton , I known but there are some formating issue that why I did that.

Comment: I want to pass the placeholder image path in my API, but when I use getDefaultPlaceholderUrl() it generates image path like: 

http://example.com/static/version1551260928/webapi_rest/_view/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/image.jpg

Answer (score 7):

If you check your store settings you will find option of Product Image place holders

```
Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders
```

You can call the get the value in block and call in your template file.

```
<?php 

protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct
(
    ---
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ---

){
    ---
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ---
}

public function getPlaceholderImage(){
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/image_placeholder'); // Base Image
    $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/small_image_placeholder'); // Small Image
    $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/swatch_image_placeholder'); // Swatch Image
    $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/thumbnail_placeholder'); // Thumbnail Image
}
```

In Your Template File Call

```
$block->getPlaceholderImage();
```

Answer (score 4):

We should take a look at the Magento Helper class [`\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Image.php)

For example :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as HelperFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;

class Image
{
    /**
     * @var HelperFactory
     */
    protected $helperFactory;

    /**
     * @var Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepos;

    /**
     * Image constructor.
     * @param HelperFactory $helperFactory
     * @param Repository $repository
     */
    public function __construct(
        HelperFactory $helperFactory,
        Repository $repository
    ) {
        $this->assetRepos = $repository;
        $this->helperFactory = $helperFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get image url
     *
     * @param $product
     * @param $imageId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getImageUrl($product, $imageId = null)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        if ($imageId == null) {
            $imageId = 'cart_page_product_thumbnail';
        }
        $helper = $this->helperFactory->create()
            ->init($product, $imageId);
        return $helper->getUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Get small place holder image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlaceHolderImage()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        $helper = $this->helperFactory->create();
        return $this->assetRepos->getUrl($helper->getPlaceholder('small_image'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the placeholder image url on the product listing page template, do this:

```
$imageUrl = $block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'category_page_grid')->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 3):

In block, use following method:

```
public function getPlaceholderImage() {
    return sprintf('<img src="%s"/>', $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get it in any template file. You'll need Magento's image helper. `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class`

You can get an instance like this at the top of any .phtml file

```
$imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);
```

and get the path to the placeholder image url like this

```
$imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image')
$imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image')
```